# pytelegrambotapi, история сообщений пользователя

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

я использую python 3.11 и telebot (pyTelegramBotAPI), у меня есть бот, который имеет несколько команд, которые получает от пользователя, каждая команда реализована в отдельном message_handler

условно пользователь пишет:
/cmd1 данные1

- получает какой-то результат

/cmd2 данные2

- получает какой-то результат

/cmd3 данные3

- получает какой-то результат

мне нужно написать обработчик /cmd4, который бы брал последнюю введенную /cmd1 от этого пользователя и ее данные и заново выполнял. Могу ли я сделать, не сохраняя где-то данные последней введенной /cmd1 для каждого из пользователей, общающихся с ботом, чтобы бот подгружал с сервера чат с этим пользователем и искал в нем последнюю введенную /cmd1?